# django model setting up, using foreignkey of foreignkey

Tags: python, django

so I'm doing a small project to learn django,and I'm so confused about setting up db.

I have 3 Video Categories: 
Chelsea, Barcelona, and RealMadrid.

Under that 3 videos there are seasons:
Chelsea - season1 season2 .....season n
same for Barcelona and RealMadrid

Under the season, there are videos

this is how I set it up so far but confused

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Season(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
class Content(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
```

So the content of the foreignkey of foreignkey. Is this the valid way?and how do I get team name from the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must retrieve a content object in any way, e.g. like this:

```
content = Content.objects.get(id=0)
```

then you can refer to the team name by:

```
cotent_name = content.season.team.name
```

Also, if you want to filter the contents by the team name, you could do:

```
barca_contents = Content.objects.filter(season__team__name="Barcelona")
```

That would return a QuerySet with all the contents of the team Barcelona.

Comment: ok thank you I understand your explanation, is there a better way to model my code though? it seems like I'm dividing them up too much. I can just put all of them in one table

Comment: Your code looks fine. You are supposed to organize your models by subject, logic, relations and efficiency. A team is a logic unit. A team have multiple seasons, but a season belongs to a team, so a many-to-one (ForeignKey) is a perfect fit. Also, consider adding a `on_delete` specification to your relations. E.g., if you have a season with a foreign key to a team with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, then if you delete a team, all seasons related to it will be deleted too. The reverse doesn't apply: you can add or remove season and this doesn't affect the team entries.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally fine to follow a relation (in both directions) to get needed data.
Thats in fact the basic idea of a relational database.

You might want to utilize the [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method of QuerySets to get the related model with the initial query as you need to get it anyway.

Comment: ok, I understand I can use select related to get the team name for the contents. did I model my database in the most efficient way?

Comment: No, you get your team name every time you try, but django is super lazy by default  and would make a second query to get the related season and  a third query to get the team (name). You just minimize the amount of queries to the database with select_related().
Your database looks fine, but you may want to read something about database normalization ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization )

Comment: i'm sorry but I'm having hard time understanding it, so using select_related I can do it like Content.objects.select_related(season)??right now content has two foreignkeys season and team.